# Creating a project to be reused

Tags: android, project

I'm sure you can help such a newbie like I am.
I created a project in android and I want to use it as a model for next 10 and more apps, just changing the raw sources.
I mean I want to make some products i.e. 10 videocharts about norway, I make one project with the needed activity and resources so each app will differ only for the content value.
I will keep of course the same file name too if needed.
How can I save the project? 
Cause I tried to make a new project from resource but I get an error on top of the tab saying Manifest is not present in the folder while manifest is actually there, and I cannot proceed further.

Thank you
ANgelo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a place to use an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

Comment: Hi, Do you mean I can create a project library then use it. But can I create a project library from an existing project or I have to do it from the beginning? Besides, when I use a project library can I change inside values? Please, be patient with me I'm not an experienced developer but a content producer. Thank you . Angelo

Comment: Thank you I carefully read your link supplied and found the answers. Have a great time. Angelo